# Check document status DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

How can I check if a document is signed with DocuSign API? Exists any API service that lets me know the document status?

I tried to obtain all objects in "completed" folder but the response doesn't contains documentId and I can't know which of documents is each of the objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DocuSign tracks **Recipient** status and **Envelope** status (but not **Document** status). In other words:

- If **Envelope** status = Completed, you can safely assume that each
  Recipient in the envelope workflow supplied all information that the
  Sender marked as Required.
- If **Recipient** status = Completed, you can safely assume that the
  Recipient supplied all information that the Sender marked as Required
  for him/her.

You have several options for determining the status of a Recipient or an Envelope:

- Use the DocuSign REST API (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/). If you're wanting to query for the status of a single envelope-- the operation is:  GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envId}}
- Use the DocuSign SOAP API (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf).
- Use DocuSign Connect, such that Connect will notify your "listener" application about Envelope and/or Recipient statuses that you specify. [See here](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect)

Finally, when querying for Envelope status using either the REST API or SOAP API, keep in mind the polling limitations that DocuSign imposes on the request status operations. These limitations are described in the [API Best Practices guide](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/SOAP_REST_API_Best_Practices_with_Connect_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I will try getting all completed envelopes and then getting the list of envelope documents for their download with their uri.

Comment: You saved my life today ^^ Going into the API reference make me lost ^^

Comment: As of today, reference to APIs has changed: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api